# UberMenu list current user's posts as menu items

Tags: posts, shortcode, users

I'm attempting to turn users' posts into menu items, without luck.

Here's what I have so far, but not working. I would like to use the Advanced custom content by adding a shortcode.

```
add_shortcode( 'current-posts' , 'ss_get_current_posts' );
function ss_get_current_posts(){
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
$author_query = array('posts_per_page' => '-1','author' => $current_user->ID);
$author_posts = new WP_Query($author_query);
while ($author_posts->have_posts()) : $author_posts->the_post();
    $list = '<ul class="ubermenu-submenu ubermenu-submenu-id-122-col-0 ubermenu-submenu-type-stack">';
    $list .= '<a class="ubermenu-target ubermenu-target-with-icon ubermenu-item-layout-icon_left" href="';
    $list .= the_permalink();
    $list .= '" title="';
    $list .= the_title_attribute();
    $list .= '"><span class="ubermenu-target-title ubermenu-target-text">';
    $list .= the_title();
    $list .= '</span></a></ul>';                 
endwhile;
return $list;
}
```

I can actually see the list, but not as links inside the submenu. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`the_permalink()`, `the_title()` by default `echo` their value. As you want to store that value in a variable you will need to `return` the values instead.
`get_the_permalink()`, `get_the_title()` are two similar functions that `return` the value instead of `echo`.

So you new code may look something like this:

```
$list = '<li class="ubermenu-submenu ubermenu-submenu-id-122-col-0 ubermenu-submenu-type-stack">';
$list .= '<a class="ubermenu-target ubermenu-target-with-icon ubermenu-item-layout-icon_left" href="';
$list .= get_the_permalink();
$list .= '" title="';
$list .= get_the_title();
$list .= '"><span class="ubermenu-target-title ubermenu-target-text">';
$list .= get_the_title();
$list .= '</span></a></li>';
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any obvious reason why I'm only getting one answer from the query?

Comment: Nevermind, the <ul> was incorrect.